# How to merge Deltas?

Tags: merge, quill, delta

I have a home application that uses an editor (currently [the one from Quasar](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/editor)). It works great, except for a few details, notably concurrent writes.

I was looking at Quill and its Deltas, [which are](https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/)

> (...) suitable for Operational Transform and can be used in realtime,

As the documentation describes it,

> the way Deltas represent a document is by expressing the instructions starting from an empty document

**I could not find anything related to the correct method to *merge* Deltas.**

There seems to be no absolute indexing (only an index starting from an empty document), so I do not see how to merge two documents with a change each - in other words how to synchronize them at some point to replay the creation of the final document.

**Is there a method for that?**

Answer (score 1):

[Delta](https://github.com/quilljs/delta/) is a separate implementation of Quilljs, that's why you should review its entire API, for what you want to do a merge would be done as follows:

```js
const delta1 = new Delta([---])
const delta2 = new Delta([---])
const restored = delta1.compose(delta2)
```